# How to use FFmpeg to modify metadata downmix levels of AC3 file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata, ac3

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to modify a metadata called "downmix levels" of an existing AC3 file (Dolby Digital surround sound file)

I have tried with at least a million different combinations of the commands, like this one:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ac3 -metadata -center_mixlev=0.707 -c ac3 output.ac3
```

The FFmpeg tool does create a new `.ac3` file, but the metadata `bsi` field is still encoded to exactly the same values as the input file

The metadata is described in the link below:
http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/ac_002d3-metadata.htm.gz

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're aiming at, though it does feel like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). From the page you link, the metadata is to tell your decoder how to adjust levels if presenting in stereo. The actual audio file level is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [ac3 codec extended bitstream parameters](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Extended-Bitstream-Information-_002d-Part-1). An example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ac3 -c:a ac3 -b:a 384k -dmix_mode loro -loro_cmixlev 0.707 -loro_surmixlev 0.707 output.ac3
```

Sets ac3 stereo downmix mode to LoRo with C -3dB and Ls/Rs -3dB